# Get external id limit for an org

Tags: metadata, externalid

For my org I need to get the number of external Ids that I am allowed to create

Some time back the limit was 3, now it is 7. I have hardcoded the limit to 7 now to check if Im hitting number of External Id for an object.

I want to check if there is any API which gives me the count of number of external ids that are supported for my org

Answer (score 4):

In short, no, there isn't a direct API to determine such limits.

You shouldn't make any assumptions at all about the number of External ID fields that may be available. Even though the usual default is 7, there might be exceptions, for example, if Salesforce granted a higher limit upon request, or if the upgrade scripts missed an org and they're still at 3, etc. Also, this value might change in the future, in which case your code would return an error early when it shouldn't.

The best way to find out if you "have enough space" is to perform a validate-only deployment with your metadata payload and parse the errors you get back, if any. If the system tells you you can't have any more external ID fields, then you know you've reached the limit. This error will occur before unit tests are run, so if your deployment gets that far, you can cancel early.

This is one of those cases where it's better to just attempt the requested operation and let the platform tell you if it worked or not.